# Error occurs while deserialize json object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, deserialization

I have following JSON data:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Name1": "Test1",
"Name2": null,
"PName": "PT",
"Address1": "First",
"Address2": "Second",
"NamePreferences": {
     "Dntst": "Test1",
     "Hygntst": "Test2"
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to de-serialize it using this code:

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, (typeof(DataTable)), settings);
```

But I'm getting this error near PracticePreferences node:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: StartObject. Path '[0].NamePreferences', line 22, position 28.'

Comment: Your error mentions `PracticePreferences` on line 22, both of which aren't in your example JSON. Provide a [mre].

Comment: I have changed error, it is coming in NamePreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided json does not look like a data table nor a list of objects. It could be de-serialized to a object of a class like this:

`public class MyBaseClass{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string? Name1 {get;set;}
      public string? Name2 {get;set;}
      public string? Address1 {get;set;}
      public string? Address2 {get;set;}
      public MyChildClass? NamePreferences {get;set;}
    
    }
    
    public class MyChildClass{
      public string? Dntst {get;set;}
      public string? {get;set;}
    }`